# Is it possible to find the tangential acceleration of a projectile after a given elapsed seconds from launching?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> A sphere is launched with an initial speed of $50\,\frac{m}{s^2}$ as
>   indicated in the diagram from below. Assume that the acceleration due
>   gravity is $g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$ and the angle with the horizontal is
>   $53^{\circ}$. Given these conditions find the tangential acceleration
>   after two seconds produced the launching of the sphere.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

This problem doesn't have alternatives.

I'm confused exactly how should I approach this problem:

The only thing which I could spot is that the components would be in the form of:

$a_n=g\cos \omega$

$a_t=g\sin \omega$

where  $\omega$ is the launch angle.

But I don't know exactly how to relate this with what would be happening after two seconds from launching?. I really would appreciate an answer which can show where are the vectors for the acceleration and the angles, because I dont know how to identify them properly. Can someone help me with this matter?. Please!!.

Comment: tan(53) may come in handy ...

Answer (score 1):

The launch angle is understood as $\tan(53^{\circ}) = \dfrac45~$, as in the $3$-$4$-$5$ Pythagorean triple.

The velocity vector as a function of time $$\vec v = (v_0 \frac35,\, v_0 \frac45 - gt) = (30,\, 40 -10t)$$

At $t = 2$ we have $\vec v = (30,\,20)$

Visually this roughly looks like the velocity where the position is the second green ball from the left, with the **velocity** pointing towards upper-left.

[image]
Now, the acceleration is always just the constant gravitational pull downward. In the diagram on the right, it is labeled as "$g (-\hat y)$".

The tangential component of downward $g$ is 
$$g\cdot \frac{20}{\sqrt{(20)^2 + (30)^2 }} = g\cdot \frac2{\sqrt{13}} = \frac{20}{\sqrt{13}} \approx 5.547 ~\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$$
The direction of this $5.547$ is opposite (at this particular moment) to the velocity, towards lower left.

Comment: Can you please indicate the **meaning** of the dotted line?. In this given context the message which I'm getting is that the only total acceleration happening is due gravity and nothing else. But there isn't a centripetal acceleration. Am i right with this?. Therefore $a_t=a_g$. But why did you multiplied this by the second component of the velocity vector?. Initially I thought that you were to use the unit vector. But only using the vertical component does dismiss my initial thought. Can you explain me this part as well?.

Comment: I'm still struggling why did you multiplied $g\cdot (-\hat{y})$. The resulting $-10\hat{y}$ seems unused. In the following line what's the justification of $g\cdot \frac{20}{\sqrt{20^2+30^2}}$? Can you please explain this part?. I'm stuck there. Is it from the vector? $\left\langle 0,20 \right\rangle$. I was not asked about the direction of the tangential acceleration, but what would it be its vectorial representation? $\left\langle -30, -20\right\rangle$ can you please explain to me this part as well?. I'm stuck there.

Comment: (1) The dotted line is just a visual decomposition of the velocity vector into the vertical component $30$ and the vertical component $20$ (2) `why did you multiplied this by the second component of the velocity vector?` No such multiplication is done. The right diagram is just showing the direction of decomposition. (3)`The resulting −10y seems unused...` Indeed the algebra of the decomposition is not shown explicitly. It is the diagram that demonstrates intuitively the similarity of triangles. You can see $g\cdot \frac{20}{\sqrt{20^2+30^2}}$ from the diagram.

Comment: The question is asking you the tangential component of the acceleration, and by overlapping the vertical downward $g$ to the velocity vector, you can see which "leg" it is: the desired decomposition is similar (as in similarity in plane geometry) to the right triangle with one leg $20$, another leg $30$, and the hypotenuse $\sqrt{(20)^2+(30^2)}$. The short leg is the $20$ and the long leg is the $30$. In the diagram we can literally **see** that it is the short leg that is the desired component (that is parallel to the tangential part of the velocity vector).